# Google Maps API V3 Apply Coordinates to Request in directionsService.route

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with Directions and according with this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple?hl=es)  I create a request with the name of the places

```js
var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var request = {
  origin:start,
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

My question is simple, its posible create a request origin and destination  with coordinates something like:

```js
var start =  new google.maps.LatLng(starLatitude, startLongitude);
var end =  new google.maps.LatLng(endLatitude, endLongitude);
var request = {
  origin:start,
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would work as its documentation says the following

> **origin :**  specifies the start location from which to calculate
>   directions. This value may either be specified as a String (e.g.
>   "Chicago, IL") or as a LatLng value.

---

> **destination :** (required) specifies the end location to which to
>   calculate directions. This value may either be specified as a String
>   (e.g. "Chicago, IL") or as a LatLng value.
>   [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)